# unload kext when it is in use or retained (cannot unload)

Tags: hardware, macos, trackpad, driver, kernel-extensions

I want to disable the trackpad on my laptop without a mouse connected. I need this strange functionality because I use synergy (https://symless.com/synergy/) and game with my desktop.

This is what I have tried so far,

```
kextstat -kl | awk '{print $6}'| grep -i multi
```

which gave

```
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver
```

Thus I went ahead and ran

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver
```

which gave the error

```
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver;    services failed to terminate - 0xdc008018.

Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload)
```

To be sure, I also tried another way (which was floating around stack exchange)

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleMultitouchDriver.kext
```

which produced the same error message.

Thanks in advance! I am a new user so please excuse my poor formatting.

For reference, I am using Sierra and the latest version of MacBook Pro 13 inch (no touchbar).

In addition, these are the links I have looked at,

1. https://superuser.com/questions/606338/how-to-disable-trackpad-mouse-via-the-mac-os-x-command-line
2. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5240707?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by resetting the PRAM on my MacBook.

[How to reset NVRAM/PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

Comment: The question is asking how to perform a task, not how to "resolve an issue".